# dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed on Xcode 10 and iPhone XS but works on iPhone 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Please forgive the redundancy, I know that variations on this question have been asked and answered many times, but I have tried many of them without luck and I’m hoping for something specific to my situation.

I have an older Mac laptop (MacBook Pro Early 2011) that cannot be upgraded to Catalina and therefore I can’t upgrade to Xcode 11, I’m stuck with Xcode 10 (specifically 10.01).

I can compile (Objective C) to and run on my iPhone **7** that is running iOS 13.3.1 (latest version), but when I try this with my iPhone **XS** also running the latest iOS I get this well-known error: can not use iPhone “dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed”.

I have done the following:

- Copied the device support files from
  github:https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport/blob/master/13.3.zip
- Placed them in a couple of places (because I’m easily confused):
  /Users/berkun/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
- I have also deleted the 13.3.1 and 13.3 directories from
  /Users/berkun/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport I have gone
  to the Devices and Simulators menu and unpaired and repaired my
  phones.

Please advise on what files should be where and why would the 7 work and not the XS?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try unpairing the device and pairing it again.

see:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3jST08imY0

Comment: Tried this again and it didn't work.  Thanks though.